# tcpdf date error Message: Undefined offset: 2

Tags: date, tcpdf

i have a date (datepicker jquery) $fecha_constancia:

```
public function generarReporte(){

            $data_b = array();

            $container = $this->input->get_post('opc_report', TRUE);
            $paciente = $this->input->get_post('paciente', TRUE);
            $odontologo = $this->input->get_post('odontologo', TRUE);
            $fecha_constancia = $this->input->get_post('fecha_constancia', TRUE);
            $diagnostico = $this->input->get_post('diagnostico', TRUE);
            $reposo= $this->input->get_post('reposo', TRUE);

            $reposo = $reposo*7;
            list($day,$mon,$year) = explode('/',$fecha_constancia);
            $nueva_fecha = date('d/m/Y',mktime(0,0,0,$mon,$day+$reposo,$year));

            $data_a = array(
                'fecha_constancia' => $fecha_constancia,
                'diagnostico' => $diagnostico,
                'fecha_reposo' => $nueva_fecha,
                'dias_reposo' => $reposo
```

but when I'm going to spend the time to the Make pdf throws me the following result:

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined offset: 2
Filename: controllers/constancia.php
Line Number: 38

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined offset: 1
Filename: controllers/constancia.php
Line Number: 38

is that the problem is in the date but not how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Check that the value of $fecha_constancia is an actual date in the format of Day/Month/Year.

This is line 38, correct?:

```
list($day,$mon,$year) = explode('/',$fecha_constancia);
```

Based on the error message, there's no slashes in $fecha_constancia. It can't assign anything to $mon and $year because explode is returning an array with a single element.